# Are there any drawbacks to having a fixed-Köhler microscope?

Tags: microscopy

I am considering to buy the Zeiss Primo star microscope. There are two variants: one with so called "Full Köhler" illumination and one with "Fixed-Köhler" illumination. Are there any drawbacks to having it fixed? When I would not want to have Köhler illumination?

Answer (score -1):

IMHO: there's hardly any reason why you should't use Köhler illumination. It's the method of choice to achieve bright and even illumination, in the entire FOV, permitting max. resolution. In a well designed system.
Köhler has only one drawback: often it turns out to be impossible to achieve even illumination at low power in the entire FOV. Usually, but not aways, the manufacturer has made provisions to achieve propper illumination at low power at the condenser level.
Allow me to add that I'm not a fan of the Primostar stand, which is a microscope build on order for Zeiss, probably by Meji.
Compared to the older Black, grey and white Zeiss Standard stands, it's a toy...

Comment: I wonder where that -1 came from